# Toggle, change html and reset form

Tags: jquery, toggle

I'm relatively new to JQuery, but I'm pretty sure this is possible...

```
<a name="formLink1">Add Item</a>

<form id="theForm" class="hidden">
(form inputs)
<a name="formLink2">Cancel</a>
<input type="submit">

<a name="formLink3">Add an Item</a>
```

If you click `formLink1` or `formLink3` above:

- the form should display
- formLink1 should have the text change to "Cancel" and the link should be set to do a "cancel" action

Clicking on either `formLink2`, or `formLink1` when the form is open (and it shows "cancel" would:

- reset the form fields to blank
  (they're all text)
- hide the form
- toggle formLink1 back to it's original text.

I've been trying a combination of `.toggle()` to flip it, and then `.html()` to write the changed text but no luck.

Can't find a search that matches close enough to what I'm doing that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for the change to bullets. I'll make a mental note of that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/ftDL8/ - DEMO

```
// switch your anchors to use classes. A href isn't a good idea, and a class
// allows us to select the multiple elements easier
$('.addItem').click(function(e){
    // if it's not already visible, show the form
    $('#theForm:not(:visible)').show();

    // prevent the anchor from firing
    e.preventDefault();
});

// again, anchor with the class
$('.cancelItem').click(function(e){
    // locate the form
    var $form = $('#theForm');

    // fire the native reset (bring all elements back to default values
    $form[0].reset();

    // now hide it
    $form.hide();

    // prevent the anchor from firing
    e.preventDefault();
});

// start off with the form hidden (using code)
$('#theForm').hide();
```

The HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="addItem">Add an Item</a>

<form id="theForm">
    <input type="text" value="Original Content" /><br />
    <input type="text" value="Default Value" /><br />
    <a href="#" class="cancelItem">Cancel</a>
</form>

<a href="#" class="addItem">Add an Item</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, change the `<a name=` bit to `<a id=`. The `name` attribute is a deprecated attribute originally used to do anchor links. It was replaced by the `id` attribute.

Then:

```
$('#formLink1').click(function(){
    $a = $(this);
    if ($a.text() == 'Add Item') {
        $('#theForm').show();
        $a.text('Cancel');
    } else {
        $('#theForm').hide();
        $a.text('Add Item');
    }
    return false;
});
```